# How to back up text messages from iPhone 5S?

Tags: backup, iphone

What is the most simple way (for a non-techie) to back up my text messages, including the pictures within iMessages?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the right way on doing that is with an iTunes Back-up. This way you make sure you can restore them back to your device anytime you want without loosing any of them including the images.

Also there are few apps out there that could help you export the messages, but not sure if they can be imported back to your device. For example using an app for Mac called **iExplorer**.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes backup (to the desktop) creates SQLite database on your local hard drive.  If you are saving the info on your local desktop machine there are free tools available that will get the data for you.

One tool works thru the browser, and retrieves your SMS messages from the SQLite database.   It saves the SMS text messages as PDF / html or XL file.
http://www.iphone-sms.com/

Here's another tool that seems to work well, does not only text messages but a lot of other content as well. It appears to be free, not sure where their revenue is coming from? 
http://www.itunesextractor.com/transfer-text-messages-from-iphone-to-computer.html